# Meteor package - how to add js file to <head> area

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I wanna do a really simple task. I have a static js file in `/packages/my-package/files/file.js` (generated by bower), and wanna add this automatically into the `<head>` area.

I am not new to Meteor, but i really don't get a solid understanding of how this package thing works. :/

What I have to do?

Thanks
Ron

Comment: Anything that's part of an Atmosphere (Meteor) package, and set to be available on the client side, is automatically bundled into your javascript for you. There's no need to add a reference in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: that was the question in my head @BrianShamblen ;) Thanks.